# Taylor epxansion of an extended odd function x^2

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Let's say I have a function **f** given by:

**f(x)=x^2 if x>0 otherwise -x^2**

and the Taylor expansion given by:

**Tf(x)=∑a_i x^i**

So I assume the Taylor expansion of the function will contain only odd powers. How to compute it?

Comment: Hint:  try to compute $f''(0)$.

Comment: Ok, I see. But if this means that there is no Taylor epxansion, there still must be some kind of polyonomial epxansion to approximate the function. Also, I forgot to mention the fact that the function is constrained between -1 and plus 1, so it allows for some polynomial expansion, right?

Comment: Sure, there are polynomial approximations to any half-way sensible function.  But you need to say what metric you are using to evaluating these.  One obvious thought is to minimize $\int_{-1}^1\left(p_n(x)-f(x)\right)^2\,dx$ for each degree $n$.  A cheaper method is to just pick a few values and interpolate.  Depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see. Thanks lulu. I'll look into this. Also, do you know the name of that integral square error optimization?

Comment: Oh, it's just the natural extension of the standard least squares metric (the usual error estimate one seeks to minimize in optimization problems).  There are other choices you could make, of course.  You could, say, use $| p_n(x)-f(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks lulu. Oh, btw, would you happen to know of any solvers that solve this polynomial optimization?

Comment: You might want to look into [Chebyshev series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#As_a_basis_set).

Comment: For fixed degrees this is not difficult.  Split the integral from $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$.  Expand the integrand and integrate term by term.  Now set the gradient to $\vec 0$.  You'll get a system of linear equations which your system should easily be able to handle.  This is one strong reason Least Squares is so beloved...it is analytically quite tractable.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion to the zeroth order is $0$.

The Taylor expansion to the first order is $0+0\cdot x$.

The Taylor expansion to the second order does not exist because of $f''(0)$.

Comment: Hey, I wrote Taylor expansion but am actually looking for a polynomial expansion.

Comment: @Sadikov: you should explain what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor expansion is extension of intermediate theorem, so it’s limited to (x, x+h), so I guess it’s inherently single side? It’s double side only when $f^{(n)}(x+0)= f^{(n)}(x-0)$, which in your example is not true.

Beside Taylor expansion is approximation of function by powers. So in your examples you get the expansion just as itself.

So you will get the Taylor expansion like $f(x+0)=x^2, f(x-0)=-x^2$, which involves powers of even order but simply negative of each other on two sides.